# "URL key for specified store already exists" when updating an existing product?

Tags: magento2, product, repository

I am getting the above error on a limited number of products, when loading and saving them with this code:

```
$product = $productRepo->get($_sku);
$product->setStockData(['qty'=>$new_qty,'is_in_stock'=>($new_qty > 0 ? true : false)]);
$product->save();
```

I can't identify anything unusual with this (simple) product, but of course something must be amiss, has anyone come across this on their site?

Answer (score 1):

If Magento is not trying to create a new product, check if your products already don't have the same url key (it must be unique).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue when attempting to use System->Import with a CSV file when importing a large number of products. I generated the CSV with a MySQL query and, [using this UDF](http://www.rummandba.com/2011/02/mysql-function-to-remove-non.html), generated my own URL Key for each product rather than allowing Magento to generate it.

So, my SELECT statement has the following for generating the URL Key:

```
CONCAT(LOWER(REPLACE(remove_non_alphanum_char_f(TRIM(`Description`)), ' ', '-')), '-', `Internal ID`,FLOOR(10000 + RAND() * 89999)) AS url_key
```

Working from inside-out:

- Remove trailing spaces from my `Description` field using MySQL's TRIM() function
- Using the UDF ("[remove_non_alphanum_char_f()](http://www.rummandba.com/2011/02/mysql-function-to-remove-non.html)"), remove non-alphanumeric characters by replacing them with hyphens
- Lowercase the string using MySQL's LOWER() function
- Using MySQL's CONCAT() function, concatenate the resulting string with my product's Internal ID *AND* a randomly-generated integer. You may not wish to include your own product ID, BUT THE RANDOMLY-GENERATED INTEGER IS IMPORTANT! It's what'll make your URL Key for this particular product unique from others that might have a similar product name.

There's probably a more-elegant way to do this but it got me over the hump on this recurring URL Key issu.  Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You should not save your product using `$product->save()`, but instead you should use the Repository `$productRepo->save($product)`. This is the Magento2 way.

Or alternatively you should be sure that the url_key is loaded into your product before attempting to save. I saw that this error appears when trying to update a product when it's url_key is not among its `_data` properties.

Comment: productRepo gives an error when no product is found. stuck with factories.